# Why do we holler *at* someone but talk *to* someone?

Tags: prepositions

Why is there a difference between using "at" and "to"? Why can I not holler *to* someone or talk *at* someone? Further, why do we chat *with* someone? Why do the prepositions change with each verb?

Comment: Talk to, talk with, and talk at are all valid - as are talk for and talk over.  The preposition changes the meaning of the verb.

Comment: It's like _listen to_ but _look at_. Each verb that needs a preposition to achieve transitivity determines its own prepositions, arbitrarily. That is, there is no reason, that' just the way it is. Like spelling. Just as verbs determine what can be their subject and object and complement, they determine the prepositions that may be used with them. Arbitrarily. As I used to tell my grammar classes, verbs have more fun.

Comment: When you talk at someone they likely aren't listening.

Comment: @JohnLawler: That's disingenuous, and unhelpful. Certainly there are many verbs that always take a particular preposition for which there is no discernible reason - and it's clearly impossible to come up with rules that cover *all* cases. But in many (most?) cases there are particular themes or ideas conveyed by prepositions, which influence the choice - so, for instance, it is possible for a speaker to coin a new phrase using a verb and preposition, and have the meaning understood immediately by other speakers. If the choice of preposition were 100% arbitrary, that would not be the case.

Comment: In **some** cases there are particular themes. Not in most. The majority of prepositions that are governed by predicates (instead of forming independent adverbial phrases like _in the garden_, where the  semantics of the prepositions is more prominent) are arbitrary, and do not relate to the semantics of the preposition. Prepositions, like conjunctions, complementizers, determiners, and quantifiers, are part of the machinery and don't have much meaning by themselves.

Comment: @JohnLawler: (1) Please @-tag when replying! (2) Interesting that you say "not in most" - do you have any pointers to any stats about this? (3) In any case, it's still very unhelpful to post that "there is no reason", when the case in this question is *clearly* one in which a consistent theme is present, where *to* implies an action directed towards someone with some degree of their interaction/consent, contrasting with *at* where it is directed towards them without their will/involvement - cf "throw a ball to"/"throw a ball at", "talk to"/"talk at", "sing to"/"sing at" etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can also *holler to* someone. In that case, the person you are hollering to is typically far away. You are trying to send a message across a great distance, so you must holler.

*Hollering at* someone is simply yelling at them, i.e., talking loudly.

What's more, you can *talk at* someone. In this case, the communication is typically one-sided: you are talking, whether or not the other person wants to hear you or is listening.

When *at* is used (with *holler*, *yell*, *talk*,..., even *whisper*) there is often a sense of aggression. The point is to be heard, typically loudly, and not necessarily to communicate or to be listened to.

(As @AndriyM noted in a comment, the same difference applies to, for example, *throw to* versus *throw at*.)

Comment: As I read your answer another example comes to mind: "read to" and "read at".  In the 1955 Elia Kazan's "East of Eden", Kate says about Adam "Always so right himself. Knowing everything. Reading the Bible at me!"

Comment: @Centaurus: Yes. And there are probably other such examples.

Answer (score 2):

The choice between "to" and "at" (and a few others), when communicating vocally with another human, basically has to do with whether you have their attention and interest.

If you are carrying on a normal conversation, you are talking *to* the other person (and they are talking *to* you).  (Note that you can also talk *with* them, implying two-way communications.)

When, however, a parent is telling a teenager something the teenager doesn't want to hear, and thus the teenager is tuning it out, the parent is talking *at* the teenager.

When yelling the same applies, except that one might yell *at* some stranger on the street to warn them that a car is coming.  In this case they're not intentionally ignoring you, but you do not yet have their attention/interest.

On the other hand, if your friend Bill is standing on that hill over there, facing you and listening, and you are trying to tell him something, you may *yell* (or *shout* or *holler*) *to* him, simply because if you *talk* in a normal voice he won't be able to hear you.

Answer (score -1):

Each verb licenses specific prepositional phrases as complements. They are all different, and there is no logic behind it.

Comment: But there really is nothing else to say or explain. Each verb has unique complements.